# how to itteratively or recursively diff a structure such as a C/C++ structure as it changes

Tags: c, data-structures, difference, recursive-datastructures, set-difference

this might seem like an overly complex or overly simple question,

but how would one go about diffing a C or C++ structure or similar, looking for values that either change or do not change, taking into account the existance of sub structures and pointers to sub structures such as `struct b substruct[5];`

basically mimicking the classic "search memory addresses x to y and log each address according to a condition then repeat" approach of searching for reliable/unreliable addresses for values, except applied to a structure instead

the structure can be obtained (usually) via any good debugger such as `gdb`'s `p` option or the python api in `gdb`

or `radare2` but i have no idea how to do that with a binary file's struct

the closest i have is

```
[0x000051c0]> "td struct foo {char* a; int b;}"
[0x000051c0]> tp foo
```

but that does not print the files internal struct itself like `gdb`'s `p`, only the one declared in `radare2`

or via the source code itself

note i can obtain the structure via gdb (with some bugs such as direct and indirect recursion loops due to something such as this):

NOTE: all following structures are generated via the gdb python api unless stated otherwise

an obvious example:

```
struct a {
    struct a b;
} a; // not generated
a.b = a; // a.b now loops back to self resulting in a direct recursion loop, a.b == a thus a.b.a.b.a.b.a.b == a
```

and a more complex example:

```
struct a{
    int val1;
    int val2;
    struct a * next;
    char * string
}; // not generated
struct a * linked_list;
linked_list = malloc(1*sizeof(struct a));
*linked_list = (struct a) {20,20,NULL,"HI"};
(*linked_list).next = malloc(1*sizeof(struct a));
*(*linked_list).next = (struct a) {5,5,NULL,"HI"};
(*(*linked_list).next).next = malloc(1*sizeof(struct a));
*(*(*linked_list).next).next = (struct a) {5,5,NULL,"HI"};
```

which would produce

```
struct a {
    int val1 = 20;
    int val2 = 20;
    struct a {
        int val1 = 5;
        int val2 = 5;
        struct a {
            int val1 = 5;
            int val2 = 5;
            struct a * next = NULL;
            char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
        }  next;
        char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
    } * next;
    char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
} * linked_list;
```

however if we change

```
*(*(*linked_list).next).next = (struct a) {5,5,NULL,"HI"};
```

to

```
*(*(*linked_list).next).next = (struct a) {5,5,linked_list,"HI"};
```

we then get

```
struct a {
    int val1 = 20;
    int val2 = 20;
    struct a {
        int val1 = 5;
        int val2 = 5;
        struct a {
            int val1 = 5;
            int val2 = 5;
            struct a {
                /* loops back to struct a { ... } * linked_list; thus entering indirect infinite recursion */
            } * next // not generated as script does not handle recursion yet
            char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
        }  next;
        char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
    } * next;
    char * string = 0x555555554b94 "HI";
} * linked_list;
```

but this is not really about preventing recursion though it helps to know where and how it can occur in a structure or similar so the diff does not enter a infinite recursion itself depending on how it will work whether by tracing, analysis or other means

in theory a diff'd structure should look something like this

considering the following structure changes of `struct a` declared in the complex example:

```
struct a {
  int val1 = 5;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} A;
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * A_PTR_ONE_STAR;
struct a {
  int val1 = 21;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} ** A_PTR_TWO_STAR;
struct a {
  int val1 = 22;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} *** A_PTR_THREE_STAR;
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a {
    int val1 = 5;
    struct a * next = NULL;
    int val2 = 0;
    char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
  } * next;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * linked_list;
```

a diff should produce the following

we shall not impose strict conditions such as a value must not occur more than once as that would be unfair tho could be used for testing for values that are unique in that they never occur more than once

we shall use the following initial struct for both conditions to avoid duplication in both examples

```
original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 5;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} A;

diff:
struct a {
  int val1 = 5;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} A;
```

if condition is values that have changed:

```
original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * A_PTR_ONE_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  NULL
  NULL
  NULL
} * A_PTR_ONE_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 21;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} ** A_PTR_TWO_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  int val1 = 21;
  NULL
  NULL
  NULL
} ** A_PTR_TWO_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 22;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} *** A_PTR_THREE_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  int val1 = 22;
  NULL
  NULL
  NULL
} *** A_PTR_THREE_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a {
    int val1 = 5;
    struct a * next = NULL;
    int val2 = 0;
    char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
  } * next;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * linked_list;

diff:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  NULL
  NULL
  NULL
} * linked_list; // not generated
```

and for the condition that values must not change:

```
original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * A_PTR_ONE_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  NULL
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * A_PTR_ONE_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 21;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} ** A_PTR_TWO_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  NULL
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} ** A_PTR_TWO_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 22;
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} *** A_PTR_THREE_STAR;

diff:
struct a {
  NULL
  struct a * next = NULL;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} *** A_PTR_THREE_STAR; // not generated

original:
struct a {
  int val1 = 20;
  struct a {
    int val1 = 5;
    struct a * next = NULL;
    int val2 = 0;
    char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
  } * next;
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * linked_list;

diff:
struct a {
  NULL
  NULL
  int val2 = 0;
  char * string = 0x555555554b44 "HI";
} * linked_list; // not generated
```